# Merging two programs in linux while preserving functionality

Tags: c, linux, executable, binaryfiles

In Linux, is it possible to merge two binary programs into a single executable while still allowing both programs to execute?

I have several program binaries without source code and I wish to append them with my small program to display additional data for the user. Here is a small example:

prog1.c displays time information:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){

    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm time_stamp = *localtime(&t);

    printf("Date: %d-%d-%d (mm/dd/yyyy) \n",time_stamp.tm_mon+1,time_stamp.tm_mday, time_stamp.tm_year+1900);
    printf("Time: %d:%d \n", time_stamp.tm_hour, time_stamp.tm_min);
    return 0;
}
```

prog2.c displays author info:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    printf("INFO: Originally developed by Jake.");
}
```

I wish to append prog1 with my prog2 such that calling prog1 will execute the prog2 and display author info as well. Output would look like:

```
Date: 11-19-2015 (mm/dd/yyyy) 
Time: 11:46
INFO: Originally developed by Jake.
```

The idea sounds similar to self-extracting archives but have not seen a working example. Simply appending prog2 to the end of prog1 using cat, dd etc. attaches the prog2 but will not execute it.

Comment: Why not write a shell script: `./prog1; ./prog2` ?

Comment: Would there be anything wrong with a bash or batch script which simply calls the 2 C executables in the order you want?

Comment: Depending on the distro, you can make the two binaries `dependencies` so if the user want's to install them using a package manager, they will be asked to download these two other programs too, then you can just call them with bash. Or you can bundle these programs with yours and use bash again, like other comments said.

Comment: use system command to call the secound program

Comment: **Why do you ask?** What is the actual problem you want to solve? What are really `prog1` & `prog2`? Pleae **edit your question** to improve it. Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1):

> In Linux, is it possible to merge two binary programs into a single executable while still allowing both programs to execute?

Of course that is impossible in general, and such an impossibility is not specific to Linux. AFAIK all the major OSes also have it. Read about [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable), [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_code), [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), [linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) and Levine's book [*Linkers & loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/).

If you have access to the source code of both `prog1` and `prog2` (and you apparently don't) you might transform each of them to become a [shared library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29#Shared_libraries), then code a wrapper which would dynamically loads one of them, e.g. with [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)

You could also change the source code to remove any potential name conflict (hence avoid having the same name defined in both), rename `prog1`'s `main` to `prog1_main`, rename `prog2`'s `main` to `prog2_main`, and have a simple wrapper like

```
  extern int prog1_main(int, char**);
  extern int prog2_main(int, char**);
  int main(int argc, char**argv) {
     if (!strcmp(basename(argv[0]), "prog1")
        return prog1_main(argc, argv);
     else if (!strcmp(basename(argv[0]), "prog2")
        return prog2_main(argc, argv);
     else { fprintf(stderr, "bad program name %s\n", argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
  }
```

IIRC, SunOS3 did such tricks in 1987... (at that time, shared libraries did not exist as we have them today)

<sup>(Such a trick might not always work for C++, because it can have static data with constructors to be called *before* `main`, etc...)</sup>

Without source code, you might embed the binary executable of both `prog1` and `prog2`  as *data* of another `mixprog.c`, compare `argv[0]` like above, and *extract* either `prog1` or `prog2` in some directory (perhaps a temporary one), then execute it (perhaps with [execveat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execveat.2.html) on that directory). There might be both technical and legal issues with such an approach.

Alternatively, if `prog2` *only* shows some message (which is unlikely), you might extract it with [strings(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strings.1.html)

BTW, if both `prog1` and `prog2` are from your Linux distribution, they are likely to be [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), and you should work on their source code. If one of them is [proprietary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_software), be sure that its license permits you (legally) to do what you imagine.

Answer (score 0):

If *prog1* doesn't need to execute anymore once *prog2* is launched, then you can make *prog1* invoke *prog2* through one function of the [`execv()` family](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv).

Comment: But OP "have several program binaries *without* source code"